# How to use the Tile Server to fetch latitude/longitude data

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, tilemill, osm2pgsql, nominatim

I have installed a tile server using the following [link](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/) and my main purpose was to geocode as many times as possible. Initially I was using openstreet API to geocode but they have certain limits so they suggested me to build my own server. In my current server I have loaded the California data into PostgreSQL server and now want to use it as a geocoder. If you see their server running process :

> Testing your tileserver
>
> Now that everything is installed, set-up and loaded, you can start up
>   your tile server and hopefully everything is working. We’ll run it
>   interactively first, just to make sure that everything’s working
>   properly. Remember to substitute your username again:
>
> sudo mkdir /var/run/renderd
>
> sudo chown username /var/run/renderd
>
> sudo -u username renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf
>   and on a different session:
>
> service apache2 reload

My server is also running without any error as you can see in the below picture.

[image]

How can I use it to extract latitude and longitude of my addresses?

There is no information regarding this on the link. My database contains the following table here and data is loaded. I want to extract latitude/longitude from it and pass as many queries as possible.

```
            List of relations
 Schema |        Name        | Type  |   Owner
  --------+--------------------+-------+------------
 public | planet_osm_line    | table | openstreet
 public | planet_osm_nodes   | table | openstreet
 public | planet_osm_point   | table | openstreet
 public | planet_osm_polygon | table | openstreet
 public | planet_osm_rels    | table | openstreet
 public | planet_osm_roads   | table | openstreet
 public | planet_osm_ways    | table | openstreet
 public | spatial_ref_sys    | table | openstreet
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of a tile server is to deliver *[tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles)* (raster *images*).

If you want to geocode then use/install a geocoder, for example [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). If you want to access raw data then use/install a service offering raw data, for example [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).

Comment: ... or see more OSM based geocoders in the listing at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines